# Html.DropDownList SelectedValue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu

How can set the selected value of a dropdownlist? When the dropdownlist is binded the selected value/item should be the most recent data that was saved in the database.
Here's What I've got so far:

**Controller:**

```
int userid = int.Parse(UserID);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserID))
{
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> address = db.Address
    .Where(c => c.UserID == userid)
    .OrderByDescending(c => c.ID)
    .Select(c => new SelectListItem
    {
        //make drop down list multi line 
        // display complete address
        Value = c.ID.ToString(),
        Text = c.StreetName + ", " + c.City
    });

    ViewBag.AddressID = address;
}

return View();
```

**Controller:**

```
@Html.DropDownList("AddressID", null, "Select Address", new { @class = "dropdown-toggle col-md-9 form-control" })
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

In it the   `Model.values` I mentioned about the list you passed.
and the Value defined the value of each option in dropdown.
and the Text defined the Text value that you able to see in the dropdown
and the value i set as 4 id denote the value of selected text from database.

Note: `new SelectList(Model.values, "Value", "Text", "4")` in it the 4 I defined in here is the value of your selected address. Please pass the value of selected text in the area.

Please try the below code.

```
@Html.DropDownList("AddressID", new SelectList(Model.values, "Value", "Text", "4"), "Select Address", new { @class = "dropdown-toggle col-md-9 form-control" })
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the following

```
  int userid = int.Parse(UserID);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserID))
    {
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> address = db.Address
        .Where(c => c.UserID == userid)
        .OrderByDescending(c => c.ID)
        .Select(c => new SelectListItem
        {
            //make drop down list multi line 
            // display complete address
            Value = c.ID.ToString(),
            Text = c.StreetName + ", " + c.City
        });

        ViewData["DropDownSource"] = address.ToList();
    }

    return View();
```

In the View

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AddressID, new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["DropDownSource"], "Value", "Text", Model.AddressID), "Select Address", new { @class = "dropdown-toggle col-md-9 form-control" })
```